# Staging Deleted files

Tags: git, git-add, git-rm, git-stage

Say I have a file in my git repository called `foo`.

Suppose it has been deleted with `rm` (not `git rm`).  Then git status will show:

```
Changes not staged for commit:

    deleted: foo
```

How do I stage this individual file deletion?

If I try:

```
git add foo
```

It says:

```
'foo' did not match any files.
```

**Update (9 years later, lol):**

This looks like it has been fixed in git 2.x:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.25.1

$ mkdir repo

$ cd repo

$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in repo/.git/

$ touch foo bar baz

$ git add foo bar baz

$ git commit -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 79c736b] initial commit
3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 bar
create mode 100644 baz
create mode 100644 foo

$ rm foo

$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
    deleted: foo

$ git add foo

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
    deleted:    foo
```

Comment: Was this a problem in old Git versions? Nowadays it doesn't seem to be one, it works similar to modified files.

Comment: @cst1992: Yes, it looks fixed now.  `git add foo` now works.  See Update.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Since Git 2.0.0, `git add` will also stage file deletions.

[Git 2.0.0 Docs - git-add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add/2.0.0)

> < pathspec >…
>
> Files to add content from. Fileglobs (e.g. *.c) can be given to add all
> matching files. Also a leading directory name (e.g. dir to add dir/file1 and dir/file2) can be given to update the index to match the current state of the directory as a whole (e.g. specifying dir will record not just a file dir/file1 modified in the working tree, a file dir/file2 added to the working tree, but also a file dir/file3 removed from the working tree. **Note that older versions of Git used to ignore removed files; use --no-all option if you want to add modified or new files but ignore removed ones.**

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't solve the problem - and the other are more cumbersome since Git 2.0.0 - this is the best way! You have my upvote

Comment: There's an important caveat to this: something like `git add foo/*/deleted.file` won't work, because the `*` only expands to files that still exist. You can use other patterns that don't rely on files existing, though, such as `git add foo/{bar,baz,quux}/deleted.file`

Comment: @IMSoP If files have been deleted from the file system at `foo/*/deleted.file`, you can also stage them for deletion by putting single quotes around the path, including the wildcard. That prevents the operating system from trying to expand the wildcard, and instead git expands it and stages the deleted files: `git add 'foo/*/deleted.file'`.

Answer (score 600):

Use `git rm foo` to stage the file for deletion. (This will also delete the file from the file system, if it hadn't been previously deleted. It can, of course, be restored from git, since it was previously checked in.)

To stage the file for deletion without deleting it from the file system, use `git rm --cached foo`

Comment: Also you can add `--cache` flag to remove file only from repository, and leaving untouch in filesystem.

Comment: What would be the process to undo this operation, that is, un-stage the file for deletion?  Is that possible?

Comment: Just answered my own question... git reset HEAD <file> followed by a git checkout <file> seems to do the trick!

Comment: If you want to delete files in a directory, you could use          git rm -r directory

Comment: @Wooble This still gives me Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# deleted:    sites/default/settings.php How do I add the file to be committed ?

Comment: @pal4life: you don't **add** the file to be committed, since you want its deletion to be committed, not its addition. `git rm` does just that. When you next `git commit` the deletion will be committed.

Comment: Actually OP asked how to stage _already_deleted_ file and this can be done by `git status | grep 'deleted:' | cut -d':' -f2  | xargs -t   -I {}  git add  -u "{}"` . Other answers seem to be showing how to stage file removal correctly (but not how to stage already deleted files). ps. the `xargs` based command works for me on Ubuntu 12.04, however when I manually do `git add -u deleted_file.txt` it doens't work. My git is 1.7.9.5

Comment: @DimitryK: `git rm` will happily stage a file for deletion even if it's already been deleted from the filesystem. And as OP's comment on another answer points out, they wanted to stage one specific file that was already deleted.

Comment: this does not work for filenames with spaces, 'git add -u' does if needed.

Comment: `git rm` doesn't stage already removed files. It throws this error: `fatal: pathspec '~.SLDASM' did not match any files`. Here are screens with proof: https://i.imgur.com/cKNKGGe.png https://i.imgur.com/1p9JdWF.png . First screenshot clearly shows that 2 files are deleted and not staged, second screenshot shows that when I type `git rm "~$Box.SLDASM"`, it throws this error.

Comment: @KulaGGin: read the error message. It's not trying to delete a file with "$Box" in the name because your shell got rid of that for you. Add more quotes if you're going to have files with horrible names.

Comment: @DimitryK how is it better from just `git add -u`?

Comment: @Line if you're asking why this long command is better than just manually typing `git add -u <filename>` - the long command adds all of the deleted files, not just one. Otherwise, I can't remember why it is better :) as I wrote this comment 8 years ago!

Answer (score 484):

Even though it's correct to use `git rm [FILE]`, alternatively, you could do `git add -u`.

According to the `git-add` documentation:

> -u
>   --update
>
> Update the index just where it already has an entry matching [FILE]. This removes as well as modifies index entries to match
>   the working tree, but adds no new files.
>
> If no [FILE] is given when -u option is used, all tracked files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used
>   to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

Upon which the index will be refreshed and files will be properly staged.

Comment: Yes `git add -A .` will add all changes, I specifically wanted to stage one deleted file.

Comment: This will add all modified files; Not just deleted files.

Comment: That is correct. More specifically, it will stage all the changes in files that are already tracked, whether deleted or just modified. This helps when you delete multiple files and don't want to stage them individually.

Comment: Is there a way to only stage deleted files and not modified? Just curious.

Comment: I am not aware of such option. In such cases, I individually stage deleted files with `git rm file1 file2` command. If there are a lot of deleted files and less of modified, do `git add -u` followed by `git reset file1 file2` command. On the whole, I think you can't avoid individual directories or files in these cases.

Comment: I did `git add -u FolderWithDeletedFiles/` and it did what I want, thanks

Comment: This works even when the directory (folder) containing the delete file has also been deleted.

Answer (score 206):

To stage all manually deleted files you can use:

```
git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)
```

To add an alias to this command as `git rm-deleted`, run:

```
git config --global alias.rm-deleted '!git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)'
```

Comment: the $() notation aparently doesn't exist in windows bash console, leading to `unknown option \`deleted)`

Comment: I don’t think this works if you have spaces in your path, either. At least, it doesn’t on my system (with zsh).

Comment: In windows do `for /F %I in ('git ls-files --deleted') do git add -u %I`

Comment: this does not work for filenames with spaces, 'git add -u' does if needed.

Comment: Minor, but I would just replace `git rm` with `git add` since I the files are already deleted and I am only updating the index.

Comment: In Windows Powershell Core I use `git add (git ls-files --deleted)` or more bravely `git add (git ls-files --deleted) && git commit -m "deletions"`

Comment: "fatal: No pathspec was given. Which files should I remove?"

Comment: How would that work if the filenames contain spaces?

Answer (score 46):

You can use this command

```
git add `git ls-files --deleted`
```

**Explanation:**

`git ls-files --deleted` - This command will return the filenames of all deleted files.

Comment: does not work if file names have spaces

Answer (score 39):

to Add all ready deleted files

```
git status -s | grep -E '^ D' | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs git add --all
```

thank check to make sure

```
git status
```

you should be good to go

Comment: Confirming that this works. I think the lesson here though is to not do `rm <file>`, but rather `git rm <file>`

Comment: FYI: cutting on spaces causes issues if any paths have spaces in them

Comment: this does not work for filenames with spaces, 'git add -u' does if needed.

Comment: Works perfectly for me on `git version 2.15.2 (Apple Git-101.1)`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use

`git rm -r --cached -- "path/to/directory"`

to stage a deleted directory.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to simply add all the deleted files to stage then you can use `git add .`

This is the easiest way right now with git `v2.27.0`. Note that using `*` and `.` are different approaches. Using `git add *` would only add currently present files whereas `git add .` would also stage the files deleted with `rm` command.

It's obvious but worth mentioning that other files which have been modified would also be added to the staging area when you use `git add .`.

Answer (score 6):

Ian Mackinnon found the answer, but it's better with xargs:

```
git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -r0 git rm
```

As a git alias:

```
git config --global alias.rm-deleted '!git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -r0 git rm'
```

This uses xargs with NUL termination (the only byte guarranteed not to appear in a path) and the option to not run `git rm` if the file list is empty.

This syntax is also fish compatible.

Answer (score 5):

for those using git 2.x+ in powershell:

```
foreach ($filePath in (git ls-files --deleted)) { git add "$filePath" }
```