# Make GIT ignore/remove DLL,PDB and similar generated files

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have issues convicing GIT to ingore generated files

Here is an example of the files that I want to ignore

```
    modified:   BLLTarifario/bin/Debug/BLLTarifario.dll
    modified:   BLLTarifario/bin/Debug/BLLTarifario.pdb
    modified:   BLLTarifario/bin/Debug/Corte.Library.dll
    modified:   BLLTarifario/bin/Debug/Corte.Library.pdb
    modified:   BLLTarifario/obj/Debug/BLLTarifario.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
    modified:   BLLTarifario/obj/Debug/BLLTarifario.dll
    modified:   BLLTarifario/obj/Debug/BLLTarifario.pdb
    modified:   Corte.Library/bin/Debug/Corte.Library.dll
    modified:   Corte.Library/bin/Debug/Corte.Library.pdb
    modified:   Corte.Library/obj/Debug/Corte.Library.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
    modified:   Corte.Library/obj/Debug/Corte.Library.dll
    modified:   Corte.Library/obj/Debug/Corte.Library.pdb
    modified:   Tarifario.Site/bin/BLLTarifario.dll
    modified:   Tarifario.Site/bin/BLLTarifario.pdb
    modified:   Tarifario.Site/bin/Corte.Library.dll
    modified:   Tarifario.Site/bin/Corte.Library.pdb
    modified:   Tarifario.Site/bin/Tarifario.Site.dll
    modified:   Tarifario.Site/bin/Tarifario.Site.pdb
    modified:   Tarifario.Site/obj/Debug/Tarifario.Site.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
    modified:   Tarifario.Site/obj/Debug/Tarifario.Site.dll
    modified:   Tarifario.Site/obj/Debug/Tarifario.Site.pdb
    modified:   TestValidate/bin/Debug/BLLTarifario.dll
    modified:   TestValidate/bin/Debug/BLLTarifario.pdb
    modified:   TestValidate/bin/Debug/Corte.Library.dll
    modified:   TestValidate/bin/Debug/Corte.Library.pdb
    modified:   TestValidate/bin/Debug/TestValidate.exe
    modified:   TestValidate/bin/Debug/TestValidate.pdb
    modified:   TestValidate/obj/x86/Debug/TestValidate.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
    modified:   TestValidate/obj/x86/Debug/TestValidate.exe
    modified:   TestValidate/obj/x86/Debug/TestValidate.pdb
```

And here is the **.gitignore**

```
/build/
*.suo
*.user
_ReSharper.*/
*.sdf
bin/
obj/
Debug/
Release/
*.opensdf
*.tlog
*.log
TestResult.xml
*.VisualState.xml
Version.cs
Version.h
Version.cpp
*/bin/*
*/obj/*
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It looks like you had these files already committed before you added your rules to the `.gitignore` file. Git will continue to monitor files that are already being tracked.

You'll need to make a commit where you remove these files, then they should be ignored afterwards.

**Edit:** To remove a folder and it's contents recursively, use `git rm -r`, for example:

```
git rm -r "./BLLTarifario/bin/"
```

You'll need to do this for each of the `bin` and `obj` directories that you want to delete.

Optionally, you can delete the folders (since they'll be rebuilt at compile time) and run `git add -A` again to stage the deleted changes. See: [Staging Deleted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373733/staging-deleted-files)

Since I only needed to remove them from the REPO I run this command for every single file

```
git rm --cached BLLTarifario/bin/Debug/BLLTarifario.dll
```

And the final **.gitignore** file is this

```
*.cache
*.dll
*.exe
*.pdb
/build/
*.suo
*.user
_ReSharper.*/
*.sdf
*.opensdf
*.tlog
*.log
TestResult.xml
*.VisualState.xml
Version.cs
Version.h
Version.cpp
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the result if you put

```
.dll
.pdb
.cache
.exe
```

into your **.gitignore** file .

Answer (score 0):

It will simply ignore them, the reason why you need to perform `git rm -r [/bin]` is to remove the files from git tracking, simply adding them to your .gitignore file after tracking won't stop git from pushing subsequent changes to your git repository