# How to ignore files when doing commit from VS to Mac to VSTS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-mac

I'm working on a ASP.Net MVC project in Visual Studio for Mac. The version control we are using is **Azure DevOps** (previously called VSTS). So, I have checkout the code and did some modifications.

The thing here is that every time I edit something, VS to Mac shows some additional files to commit. Usually .dll, .pdb, .cache files, etc.

Is there a way to ignore those files when committing the original changes? Or is it normal?

[image: Commit view in Vs to Mac]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make GIT ignore DLL,PDB and similar generate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543997/make-git-ignore-dll-pdb-and-similar-generate-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any version control called VSTS. VSTS is the previous name of Azure DevOps.

In Azure DevOps, there is only [Git (distributed) and TFVC (centralized)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops)

If you are using TFVC, you should use .tfignore to exclude those dlls. How to you could refer my answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784750/5391065).

If you are using Git, you could use .gitignore file to handle it. Just like when working with Windows, also in Mac you are not allowed to create a file which starts with a dot.

You could take a look at the sample here: [How to create a .gitignore file for Visual Studio projects in Mac](https://christosmonogios.com/2016/11/28/How-To-Create-A-Gitignore-File-For-Your-Visual-Studio-Projects-In-Mac/)

Comment: Hi PatrickLu-MSFT. I already fixed it using the second link for Git. Also, I edited my original post to correct VSTS to Azure DevOps. Because, some changes were already committed this URL help me out as well: http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/01/Untrack-files-already-added-to-git-repository-based-on-gitignore/

Comment: @MikePR Thanks for your kindly share. Always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works!:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to have the **.gitignore** file and check in that to the version control repositories with the list of extensions which you dont need to checkin to the repo.

Based on that when ever you check in the files the specified extensions inside the .gitignore will not be checkedin to the repository.