# git: equivalent of "git add -u" with "git rm"

Tags: git

Is there a way to remove all files from the index that are deleted ?

I usually use `git add . -u` to add all files to my staging zone that are tracked and modified.
How would I do a command like `git rm . -u` ?

Comment: Are you trying to have `git` recognize that a file was deleted? `git` already tracks that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Staging Deleted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373733/staging-deleted-files)

Comment: @Ali: no, I mean, when you delete a file, git still tracks it. You need to use `git rm` to definitely remove it from your tracked files. So how can I do `git rm` to all deleted files ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: oh right, so just `git add deleted_file` would do the same as `git rm deleted_file` ! fantastic

Comment: Does `git rm` not already do what you want? I'm pretty sure it deletes the file and stages the deletion.

Comment: yes it does..... But I want to delete ALL files in just one command as `git add . -u` would add ALL tracked and modified files in one command :)

Comment: So you would like to add all files that are already deleted? Doesn't `git add .` already do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern Git, `git add -u .` already removes from the index any file that you have removed from your working tree:

```
$ mkdir t1 && cd t1 && git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo example > readme
$ echo somefile > somefile
$ git add .
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 95caaab] initial
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 readme
 create mode 100644 somefile
$ ls
readme          somefile
$ rm somefile
$ git add -u .
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    somefile
```

If you have an ancient Git, `git add -u` might not stage these removals—I can't recall the behavior of Git 1.7 here.  If so, consider using the `--all` flag.  You could also use `git status -s` to detect missing work-tree files, which will have <kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> as their two letter status:

```
$ git restore --staged somefile
$ git status -s
 D somefile
```

so that `git status -s | grep '^ D'` produces the list of such files.  Others like to use `cut` and so on to generate a removal command, but I prefer to do:

```sh
git status -s >/tmp/x
vim /tmp/x
```

and then, in the editor, use commands to delete all the non-space-D files, then turn the remaining lines into `git rm` commands:

```
:v/^ D/d
:%s/^ D/git rm/
```

for instance.  If some file names have white space, the second `vim` command would be:

```
:%s/^ D \(.*\)/git rm "\1"/
```

Some eyeball inspection will verify that this is indeed what I want to do, after which `ZZ` or `:x` exits vim with a file in `/tmp/x` that I can run using `sh /tmp/x`.  Voila, mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get brutal, the core commands are always an acceptable option:

```
git diff-files --diff-filter=D --name-only \ 
| git update-index --remove --stdin
```